# Index Company Name but not other keywords

Tags: search-engine-indexing, keywords

I'm working on a website that doesn't want it's content indexed by search engines because it only caters to a specific segment of the population. It purposefully wants to stay hidden from the general public.

It **does** want it's company name indexed in search engines however, because when the company sends targeted snail mail advertising, users should be able to type the name and find the site.

It's a requirement for the homepage to function as a gateway into the the rest of the site, so it's unavoidable that the homepage will be rich in relevant keywords that could lead to the site being found by the general public.

**Summary:** What's a good approach to have a webpage indexed solely by the company's name without generating other keyword searches related to the company?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. At first you might think you can create a page that only mentions the company's name (which would be very silly and useless but let's use it for the sake of argument). But all someone has to do is link to that page with keywords that are not the company's name (the odds are those keywords will be related to what the company does) and then it will rank for those keywords in addition to the company name.

The best you can do is block every page but the home page from the search engines and keep the content on this page to a minimum. The less text the better. Make sure the `<title>` and `<h1>` use the company name and try to keep any keyword laden text in images if possible. Essentially this page will be a landing page that will invite the user deeper into the site where more content that is not available to the search engines can be found.

Comment: Haha, you followed my train of thought well. I thought about creating a page with the company name while posting. Thanks for debugging that one.